# Calculation error when representing TDateTime (Delphi) as a Java Calendar object

Tags: java, delphi

Delphi `TDateTime` epoch is *December 30, 1899*, Java `Calendar` uses Unix epoch which is *January 1, 1970*. The following code:

```
Calendar epoch = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
epoch.set(1899, 12, 30, 0, 0, 0);
epoch.getTimeInMillis();
```

gives *-2206483199054* but according to manual calculations it has to be *-2209161600000*. Where does delta *2678400946* (31 days) come from? What am I missing?

Yes, I now I can operate with milliseconds as a workaround but I want to know where error comes from.

P.S. `epoch` is an instance of `java.util.GregorianCalendar`.

Comment: In Delphi `DateTimeToUnix(0) = -2209161600` (seconds)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The month field is 0-based, so December is month 11, not 12. That explains why you're off by 31 days — you wrapped around to January 30, 1900. You can call [`setLenient(false)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#setLenient%28boolean%29) to catch that kind of error sometimes.

The `set` method only sets the six fields mentioned in the arguments; it leaves other fields unchanged, including the millisecond field, which explains why you're actually off by *slightly more* than 31 days.

[The documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#set%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) advises you to call [`clear()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#clear%28%29) first, but you may instead prefer to call `clear(Calendar.MILLISECOND)` to keep time-zone information intact.

Comment: I suspected that but couldn't find it in documentation.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of

```
epoch.set(1899, 12, 30, 0, 0, 0);
```

use

```
epoch.set(1899, Calendar.DECEMBER, 30, 0, 0, 0);
```

because the month number is zero-based (0 = JANUARY)

The result is -2209161600000 (JDK 1.6) when milliseconds are also set to 0